# Evento botão FileUpload com submit estilo do Gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando `vb.net` e `asp.net` com `forms` e preciso adicionar um evento que ao clicar no botão de selecionar um arquivo para anexar, quando eu selecionar o arquivo ele automaticamente salvar, sem precisar ter outro botão para dar o submit. Estilo do gmail.
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Por inicio testei varias coisas porem apaguei excluindo... O código vb do button está aqui:  "<div>
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">Arquivo:</asp:Label>"                      
                        "<asp:FileUpload ID="fuArquivo" runat="server"  Width="400px" Enabled="true" CssClass="upload"/> 
                    </div>"

Comment: ha tá entendi . . .

Answer (score 1):

[Plugin jQuery uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) irá carregar com uma barra de progresso, e inclui funcionalidade para o upload de arquivos únicos ou múltiplos.

Comment: Então meu caro, eu não estou usando o php e sim o vb.net, como eu poderia no meu codigo de vb adicionar o jquery?
O código vb do button está aqui: "<div> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">Arquivo:</asp:Label>" "<asp:FileUpload ID="fuArquivo" runat="server" Width="400px" Enabled="true" CssClass="upload"/> </div>"

Comment: a ideia é a mesma, mude apenas seu backend

Comment: @durtto adicione um exemplo de como o plugin funciona e como se pode aplicar ao caso do OP para melhorar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o evento change, em javascript. Então você envia o form quando o input de arquivo disparar esse evento. 
Exemplo:

```js
file = document.getElementById("file");
form = document.getElementById("form");

file.addEventListener('change', function(){ //quando o input de arquivo mudar...
 form.submit();                          //...o form é enviado
})
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"
      method="post"
      action="seu_script.php"
      id="form">
  <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="file" />      
</form>
```

Dentro do stack overflow não vai funcionar porque ele impede o submit de form, mas você pode ver funcionando em: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpppdfwm